# Updating OTA after changing /etc/system files

Tags: updates, ota-update

I manually modified /system/etc/mixer_paths.xml in order to boost volume on my Nexus 5 when listening to music with a headset. As a result I am still running version 4.4.2 as whenever I attempt to update OTA I get "Error!" screen. I suspect it has something to do with my modification of the system files but am not sure. So I have two questions:

- What is causing the update to fail?
- How can I fix it?

I would like to do both of the above without loosing any of my data/applications.

(I would not be surprised if a question similar to this one has been asked before Android SE, but I lack experience to determine which of the questions that already exist is actually the same as my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you first need to unlock bootloader to root a nexus device (I'm not a nexus user).

Now, in order to update your OTA, it is mandatory to lock the bootloader and then perform the update. 
I'm a HTC user, and I faced the same issue. What I did was flashed the stock recovery, locked the bootloader and performed the update. Everything went smooth.

I'm sure nexus follows the same path.

Comment: What does it mean to "flash the stock recovery"? Is that something I can do quite easily?

Comment: In other words, you will have to unroot your phone.  
A tutorial [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-factory-image-t2513701) guides you how to unroot your device.  

I hope this helps.